# Creating a view with variables/parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, variables, view

I have a form that the user fills and is then directed to a view that contains the data entered. How can I create this view so that it uses variables initialized to the user's input. How should the view look like. I have read about passing parameters to a view, but I need a way to create it and then assign the parameters passed to each variable in the view.

EDIT:From Brian Roger's example

Say  have a model

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a view (which using another model called mod) like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Example", "Test", FormMethod.Get))
  {
     <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
      <input type="submit" value="Go" />
 }
```

upon filling the form, I want to get the data and display it in another view, view2

```
@model MyModel
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<h2>Example of passing data between the view and controller using a model</h2>
 @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Name))
  {
    <p>Enter your name below and click Go.</p>
  }
 else
 {
    <p>You entered "@Model.Name".
 }
```

My controller for the submit button looks like

```
public ActionResult Example(MyModel model)
{
    model.Name = mod.Name;
    return View("view2", model);
}
```

The value of mod.Name is correct but I just does not get passed to the new view

EDIT 2:

And the controller for view2 looks like this

```
public ActionResult view2(MyModel model)
{
  return View(model)
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "i have to create this view" you just need to pass the appropriate model to your view... can you post some sample code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC3, in order to pass values back and forth to a view, you use a model object.  A model object is just a C# class with some properties in it.  In your controller, you make your action method accept the model as a parameter, do any processing as needed, then return the updated model to the view as part of the ActionResult.  In the view, you can reference the model object via the Model property on the view.

Here is a contrived example.

The model class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The controller class:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Example(MyModel model)
    {
        if (model == null)
        {
            model = new MyModel();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The view (this would be Test/Example.cshtml):

```
@model MyModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Example of passing data between the view and controller using a model</h2>
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Name))
{
    <p>Enter your name below and click Go.</p>
}
else
{
    <p>You entered "@Model.Name".  If you want to change it, 
       enter a new name below and click Go.</p>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Example", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

The @model directive tells the view that the model class is `MyModel`.  So then you can reference its properties via the Model property of the view.  Name your form controls the same as the properties of the model class, so the MVC framework will place the values back into the model object when passing the model to the controller when the form is submitted.

For more in-depth examples you might want to check out some MVC tutorials, such as [these](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials).  Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Udated to show an example of getting data from one view and displaying it in another

Here is the updated controller class:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    // This method corresponds to the first view which just displays an empty form
    public ActionResult Example()
    {
        MyModel model = new MyModel();
        return View(model);
    }

    // This method corresponds to the second view which displays the data
    public ActionResult Example2(MyModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here is the first view (Views/Test/Example.cshtml) which displays the form.
Notice how it posts to the `Example2` method in the controller.

```
@model MyModel

<h2>Example view with a form</h2>
<p>Enter your name below:</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Example2", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="Name" value="@Model.Name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

Here is the second view (Views/Test/Example2.cshtml) which displays the data from the first view:

```
@model MyModel

<h2>Example view that displays data from another view</h2>
<p>You entered "@Model.Name".</p>
```

Comment: Thank you. This somewhat answer my question. In your example, say the form part of the view was another view and I want to display the data entered not on the same view but on the different view. Your example has the form and form result in the same view. How can I have that in different view? I can get the form data by having FormMethod.Get. But when I initilize my model with this data and return the view (return View("myView", model)) with the initialized data, it is always empty

Comment: Typically how you would do this is have two different methods in your controller, one for each View.  The first method just returns the view for the form.  The form in that view posts to the second method in the controller, which then returns the second view.  The second view can then display the data.  I'll update my answer to illustrate this.

Comment: Thank you. I did as you mentioned. Please see the edit. but it is not reading my model data when I open the new view

Comment: Is the form in your first view posting to the new controller method?  Is your second view using the correct model?  What happens when you step through with a debugger?

Comment: Yes and yes. When I debug, the model is being properly initialized. I think the problem is passing the initialized model to the second view and having it use the information in there. Per the edit, do you thing the controller for the second view is correct?

Comment: my bad...I was calling the model wrong. Thanks for all your help